# Applying Bayes law

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, bayes-theorem

I'm completely lost on how to do this:

---

James tries to sell Adam on an analysis, LoopFinder, that announces if a program has an infinite
loop. LoopFinder has a false positive rate of 5% (i.e. 5% chance LoopFinder announces there is an infinite loop given the program has none). Otherwise, LoopFinder is correct when a program does have an infinite loop.
To prove LoopFinder is worth his investment, Adam randomly generates a set of 98 programs and manually verifies 16 of them have infinite loops. James then runs LoopFinder on those 98 programs.

---

**On one program in the suite, LoopFinder announces there is an infinite loop. What is the probability that program actually has an infinite loop?**

How could we approach this?

Comment: I'd write up a full answer if you showed work. For now, try to set up the fraction for conditional probability. You would use Bayes Law to help set up the denominator, the probability that LoopFinder announces an infinite loop.

Comment: @RyanGreyling, would it look something like this?

Pr[LoopFinder | InfiniteLoop]

 = P[InfiniteLoop | LoopFinder] * P(LoopFinder) / P(infinite loop)

Comment: I would just go to the problem and look at what it is asking for.  It tells you the false positive rate.  You can calculate how many negatives there are, therefore you can calculate the expected number of false positives.  The total set being detected as "infinite" are the "real" ones + the "fake" ones.  Now figure out the ratios here.

Comment: On a side note, the "LoopFinder" program in question is not possible with a fixed error rate :)

Comment: I'm guessing LoopFinder represents the event that LoopFinder announces an infinite loop. No that's not right. You need to find the probability of Infinite Loop given  event LoopFinder. $P(\text{InfiniteLoop | LoopFinder})$ which equals $P(\text{InfiniteLoop and LoopFinder})/P(\text{LoopFinder})$.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the 98 programs, 16 are actually infinite loops and the rest 82 are finite.

Hence, $P$(infinite)=$\frac{16}{98}$ and $P$(finite)=$\frac{82}{98}$

Let the event of LoopFinder declaring a program as having an infinite loop be called +**ve**.

So, $P$(+ve|infinite)=1 (always true) and  $P$(+ve|finite)=5%=$\frac{1}{20}$.

We need to calculate, $P$(infinite|+ve).

You should be able to use Bayes Theorem and take it from here.